# Java - how to include the regex pattern in the character set validation error messages while doing XML import?

Tags: java, xml, import

While doing an Import of an XML, am getting the following validation error:

"Error at line 5 column 76: The value 'nodecapacity' of attribute 'name' on element 'parameter' is not valid with respect to its type, 'name'"

I am using a SAX Parser.

Also, is there a way I can get the expected regex pattern to be displayed in the error message?

Comment: (a) You haven't said which Java parser/validator you are using (there are many). (b) Is this a well-formedness error (i.e. a bad element name or attribute name), or a validation error (conflict with a regex in a user-written schema?). (c) Does the error message really contain a spelling mistake? I suspect you aren't quoting it accurately. Always give the actual error message, not a paraphrase.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different schema processor such as Saxon to see if the error messages suit you better. For example Saxon produces this:

```
Validation error on line 1 column 15 of test.xml:
  XSD99999: The content "xxx" of element <top> does not match the required simple type.
  Value "xxx" contravenes the pattern facet "[0-9]*" of the type nameType
```